# An attempt was made to insert or update columns error while updating columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to update the column with some details. But I am getting this error:

> An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which map to a non-key-preserved table.

Here is my query:

```
 UPDATE 
(
 SELECT a.SPAN_LINK_ID, a.SPAN_TYPE, a.NE_LENGTH as OLD, b.MAINT_ZONE_NE_SPAN_LENGTH as NEW
FROM app_fiberinv.tbl_fiber_inv_cmpapproved_info a
 INNER JOIN app_fiberinv.tbl_fiber_inv_jobs b
 ON a.SPAN_LINK_ID = b.LINK_ID
WHERE a.SPAN_LINK_ID IN ('DLHI_5202','TCPP_6004')) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What if you skip the *join view* and use e.g. `merge`?

```
MERGE INTO tbl_fiber_inv_cmpapproved_info a
     USING tbl_fiber_inv_jobs b
        ON (a.span_link_id = b.span_link_id)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET a.ne_length = b.maint_zone_ne_span_length
           WHERE a.span_link_id IN ('DLHI_5202', 'TCPP_6004');
```

Comment: getting `A number of attempts were made to validate or authorize an object but failed.` while updating it

Comment: That's bad news. Try to run `alter system flush shared pool;` first, then MERGE. If it still returns the same error, consider reporting it to Oracle Support.

Comment: is it ok to run that as, I am executing this code on prod environment ?

Comment: It won't "destroy" anything, if that's your concern, but it might affect performance as it clears cached execution plans and queries from memory.